# Using '-replace' operator to delete text in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a list (array) of data which contain IP address and other information:

```
$example

@{IP=192.168.1.2; otherinfo=etc; moreinfo=etc}
@{IP=192.168.1.3; otherinfo=etc; moreinfo=etc}
@{IP=192.168.1.4; otherinfo=etc; moreinfo=etc}
```

I want to keep he IP address and strip all the other text. I have seen substring and split used but I haven't had luck, only errors, so I've been using -replace.

I've had success deleting text after the IP address:

```
$example = $example -replace '(.+?);.+','$1'
$example

@{IP=192.168.1.2
@{IP=192.168.1.3
@{IP=192.168.1.4
```

Quite frankly, I am having a hard time grasping what is happening here. I found copy/pasted this and replaced the symbol with ";". I have tried googling to understand but haven't understood it yet.

I am unsure how to delete the text before and including "=".

Comment: You should show how you're populating it. You probably just need to do `$example.IP`

Comment: I am using the PSExcel Module to populate the list `$iplist = import-xlsx -path "\\shared_server" -Sheet 4 -RowStart 2 -Header IP,QID,VendorID,Severity,Title 2> $null` and am then using select string `$iplist = $iplist | Select-String -Pattern "HP Support"`

Comment: Will do. Do I check what type of array it is by $example.gettype() ?

Comment: This did retrieve only a list of IPs, but now the issue is I cannot use select-string to only keep the entries which include "HP Support" under the header called Title

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222427/discussion-between-emerson-and-doug-maurer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Import-XLSX](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSExcel/1.0.2/Content/Import-XLSX.ps1) function returns an array of PSObjects, not a string, so you should not try to use a string method like `-replace` on it.
Instead, **filter** the output using a `Where-Object` clause and finally select only the property or properties you need from the objects that passed the filter.

```
$iplist = (Import-XLSX -Path "\\shared_server" -Sheet 4 -RowStart 2 -Header IP,QID,VendorID,Severity,Title | `
           Where-Object {$_.Title -like '*HP Support*'}).IP
```

Variable `$iplist` should now be a string array with values

```
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
```

Answer (score 2):

If `$example` is an array of hashtables like it appears, then simply pull the values you want from the specific property.

```
$example = @(
    @{IP='192.168.1.2'; otherinfo='etc'; moreinfo='etc'}
    @{IP='192.168.1.3'; otherinfo='etc'; moreinfo='etc'}
    @{IP='192.168.1.4'; otherinfo='etc'; moreinfo='etc'}
)

$example.ip

192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
```

Per our discussion, this should get you the desired IPs

```
$iplist = import-xlsx -path "\\shared_server" -Sheet 4 -RowStart 2 -Header IP,QID,VendorID,Severity,Title |
    Where-Object title -match ‘HP Support’ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IP
```

Comment: The array is as it appears, however $example.ip is not working for me